# Sending incremental data to other application from Oracle database:- Even small suggestion would be very helpful

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, database-design, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 1 table lets suppose `Item`. there are many `DML` happens on this table daily. Whatever DML(Insert update delete) happens on this table I need to insert this transaction data into another application using `APIs`.

if in item table ,2 record gets inserted, 1 updated and, 1 deleted I need to inject data into another application in the below form. file will be in json format.

```
  I can create below file. My question is regarding how to extract daily transactional data.
{
  "insert": ["A1,A2"].
   "delete": "B1",
   "update": "C1 "
}
```

something like above. means if A1 A2 inserted into Item table, B1 got deleted and C1 got updated. so i will send the data in above format to target application to do changes.

To do this I created one more table `Item_trigger`. also I created `trigger` on Item table. so if any DML happens `trigger` will insert into `Item_trigger` table with value

```
('A1','Insert'), ('A2','Insert'),('B1','delete'),('C1','Update')
```

then using `Item_trigger` table I will create file and send the data to target system.

The above design have been rejected because i am using trigger.is there any good solution? I was thingking about MV but it doesn't consider delete. doesn't consider `delete` so I can not use even that.

Could you please help me with design. Is there anyway to record transaction without using `trigger`

Comment: What is 'A1', 'A2', etc.? The rows' IDs? Or all columns in a row concatenated into a character separated string, JSON, HTML, ...?

Comment: they are simple column values...you can consider them itemname

Comment: So all your trigger does is insert a row with 'insert', 'update' or 'delete' and that one column? Then it's hard to imagine that such simple trigger slows down the system significantly. I don't see how a GTT (global temporary table) can be of any benefit here or how there are even supposed to be used in this context. GTT's data is private to the session, so whatever program or user is writing to the table would have to make sure to also send the data to that other system in the same session? How would that be better?

Comment: actually @ThorstenKettner   in a day almost 100,000 transaction happens. and I have to create row level trigger. for each transaction it will get fire. to insert data into another table , is there any other approach other than trigger. I think yes you are right about GTT. I actually could not revert to boss to save my job :(

Comment: Well, I don't consider 100.000 in 24 hours that many. And the trigger is sooo simple. I suppose that someone just *thinks* that trigger *might* be slow and that someone is probably completely wrong. I suggest you just measure how much time the trigger actually takes. I.e.: Write a script to insert update or delete rows, see how much time it takes, then rollback. Do this one time with the trigger and one time without. I wouldn't expect a great difference in runtime. In my opinion a trigger is the most reliable method here. Or auditing (which isn't faster as far as I know).

Comment: I'd consider db change notifications or mview log

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov thank you Sayan. what is DB change notification?

Comment: @Shruti https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_dcn.htm#:~:text=Database%20Change%20Notification%20is%20a,DML%20or%20DDL%20transaction%20commits.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner even empty triggers make bulk inserts very slow and generate additional redo http://orasql.org/2016/09/22/how-even-empty-trigger-increases-redo-generation/

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of statement level auditing on particular table. But that will only provide the information of what type of operation has been performed but not the actual data. You can combine this information with storing the value of whatever inserted, deleted and updated in another table or use the main table to directly transmit data.

Below is the script

```
audit select,insert,update,delete on test.test_audit by access;
delete from test_audit where id <= 10;
select * from Dba_Audit_Object where OBJ_NAME='TEST_AUDIT';
```

Comment: Trigger is the best way for auditing but this is the only other way I can think of or you can simply create a small table and after every DML insert data into this table based on SQL%ROWCOUNT in PLSQL